# RealmConfiguration.Builder with DocumentFile

Tags: android, realm, android-sdcard, realm-mobile-platform

I'm struggling with storing a realm db on the sd card. The point is that I have to use DocumentFile instead of simple File object to have write access. Another words:

```
Uri uri = getUriInstanceToSaveDB(); // my inner method

new File(uri.getPath()).canWrite() == false
DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getActivity(), uri).canWrite() == true
```

Therefore I can't just store data using RealmConfiguration.Builder() (cause it uses File object as storing mechanism). Of course, I've also tried to use simple String there instead of File object - no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real doesn't support `DocumentFile` at this point in time, so I'm afraid you are currently out of luck unless you can find a way to map a DocumentFile to a local File reference.

Also one of the problems with DocumentFile is that it might reference a file that doesn't exist locally, which would prevent Realm from using it. So it is unclear if Realm could ever support this.